# Can the same origin policy be breached virtual network tests

Tags: javascript, security, virtual, same-origin-policy

I am doing research on Same origin Policy for work project

It appears same origin policy is very strong policy and can not be broken?

I have tested iframes, CSS history url hack as possible ways to break it.

I was wondering if any ideas on possible tests I could perform whether they would work or not on testing the same origin policy. Is there a simple tutorial on how to do DNS rebinding perhaps in a virtual netkit environment?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what is goal?

Comment: Trying to test if the Same Origin Policy can be breached through experiments

Comment: what's the criteria for the "breach"? what determines a breach?

Comment: SOP = "one origin should not be able to access properties of another origin" so can I get one website i.e (websiteA.com) be able to access properties of (websiteB.com) either by fooling the SOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should mater what the Same Origin Policy(SOP)  entails,  and the [Browser Secuirty Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2) is a great resource for that.

That being said there are plenty of ways that websites revoke the protection given to them by the SOP. XSS is a good example,  because this can be used to access data on another domain,  a good example of this is [the samy worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html).

Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks are not prevented by the SOP.  The idea is that you can send requests,  but you can't read the response.  In this attack the request is causing a side effect,  like changing a user's password.

Clickjacking is another example of a flaw where events(mouse move events,  click events,  keystroke events) are passed to another domain and can cause problems.

Then people intentually bypass the SOP,  CORS and JSONP is a good example. There is also flash's crossdomain.xml file.

And last but not least,  **[SOP bypass vulnerabilities are incredibly common in browsers.](http://osvdb.org/search/search?search%5Bvuln_title%5D=same%20origin%20policy%20bypass&search%5Btext_type%5D=titles&search%5Bs_date%5D=&search%5Be_date%5D=&search%5Brefid%5D=&search%5Breferencetypes%5D=&search%5Bvendors%5D=&search%5Bcvss_score_from%5D=&search%5Bcvss_score_to%5D=&search%5Bcvss_av%5D=%2a&search%5Bcvss_ac%5D=%2a&search%5Bcvss_a%5D=%2a&search%5Bcvss_ci%5D=%2a&search%5Bcvss_ii%5D=%2a&search%5Bcvss_ai%5D=%2a&kthx=search)**.

Comment: Great answer mate. Noticed you did not mention Cross-site history manipulation (XSHM)? Any ideas on perhaps getting around browser history.object in Javascript? I know the XSS Firefox bug is so old now using a:visited to see if links in current session have been clicked is there any new updates i.e. a newer alternative in web browsers? Then you can possible read responses to blind attacks like CSRF

Comment: @daza166 No I don't believe that is possible. It is possible to read the contents of a page using clickjacking,  by getting the  user to drag and drop an iframe of the `view-source:` of the page you want to read.